# put scroll bar outside div with auto overflow

Tags: html, css

I have a small div with `overflow:auto;` but when the the scroll bar appears it covers up a great deal of the div. This can be avoided by using `overflow:scroll;`, but then you get the unsightly faded scroll bar when there is no overflow. Is there a way of putting the scroll bar outside of the div without using `overflow:scroll;`? Thanks.

here is a demonstration  [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Wr6Nm/2/)

```
.alphabet{ display:inline-block;
           overflow-y:auto; 
           overflow-x:hidden;
           border:1px solid;
           height:50;
         }

<div class = "alphabet">abcdefgh<br>
                        ijklmnop<br>
                        qrstuvwx
</div>
```

Answer (score 20, accepted):

If it's an option to use a container element around `.alphabet`, you can set the vertical scroll on that. I've added the `<hr>` to fake an always-visible bottom border that won't also go under the scrollbar.

HTML:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="alphabet">
        abcdefgh<br />
        abcdefgh<br />
        abcdefgh<br />
        abcdefgh<br />
    </div>
</div>
<hr>
```

CSS:

```
.container{
    overflow-y:auto; 
    overflow-x:hidden; 
    height:50px;
    width:100px;
}

.alphabet{          
    width:100%;
    overflow:visible;
    box-sizing:border-box;
    border:1px solid;
    border-bottom:0;
}

hr{
    margin:0;
    height:0;
    width:85px;
    border:0;
    border-bottom:1px solid;
}
```

With inner border: http://jsfiddle.net/Q32gG/1/

If you don't actually care about the scrollbar showing inside the border, you can drop the `<hr>` and add a full border to `.container` instead (http://jsfiddle.net/V3MbV/3/).

Comment: Notice: This solution breaks the functionality of the browser's shortcut to scroll horizontally (shift + mouse wheel). Tested on Chrome 78.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using and outside-scrollbar, why not to use some right padding as so

```
   .alphabet{ display:inline-block;
               overflow-y:auto; 
               overflow-x:hidden;
               border:1px solid;
               height:50;
               padding-right:15px;
             }
```

Or if you prefer, using em units to match a character whatever size you are using

```
padding-right:1em;
```

PD: By the way there is a typo in your example. The period should be previous it should be .alphabet {

Comment: But the padding should be 0 (or less than 15) if the scrollbar is not displayed.

Comment: But in chrome it still takes up space inside the div even thought it's placed outside of it.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use a combination of padding right and setting the width to 100% + 10px. Works like a charm.

```css
.alphabet {
  width: 100%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border: 1px solid;
  border-bottom: 0;
  // for outside scrollbar
  width: calc(100% + 10px);
  overflow-y: auto;
  padding-right: 10px;
}
```