# Prevent y-scroll-auto changing inner width of a div

Tags: javascript, html, css

Is there a way do prevent the y-scroll-bars from changing the inner width of a div-container. Can the child of the div-container always have a right-padding until the scrollbar appears?

In the example the text has a different width according to the presence of vertical scrollbars:
[js fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/hxurwkf1/)

HTML

```
<div>
    <span>
     Lorem ipsum dol...
    </span>
</div>
```

CSS

```
div {
  border: solid 1px;
  width: 200px;
  height: 150px;
  overflow: auto;
  margin: 10px;
}

span {
  display: block;
  background: rgba(122, 150, 255, 0.23);
}
```

Comment: Have a look at this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16306322/put-scroll-bar-outside-div-with-auto-overflow

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace element by the name of element you want this functionality to be active.
 Overlay adds scroll bar on top of element rather than adding it into the element .

```
element {
   overflow-y :overlay;
  }
```

[Jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/hxurwkf1/1/)

I have updated Jsfiddle. Now both elements are identical.
Although the scroll bar will still be on top. You could the width by **initialWidth + the width of scrollbar**  using javascript but width of scrollbar is different in different browsers so please don't try that as it will cause compatibility issues.