# Place scroll bar outside div

Tags: html, css, reactjs

I'm trying to make it seem like the scroll bar is on the outside of a div that has rounded corners.

My approach was to place a div within the div where the inner div contains the content but the outer div has the overflow set to scroll.

This gets me pretty close to my desired result, except that...

1. As you can see the content spills out of the inner div (for obvious reasons).
2. when you scroll, the div itself (not just the content) scrolls as well (see second image)

Does anyone have any suggestions how to go about creating this effect?

I found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16306322/put-scroll-bar-outside-div-with-auto-overflow) which seems to be addressing the same issue but I found that this solution didn't work well for a div with rounded corners.

```js
 <div style={{ width: 330, overflow: 'scroll' }}>
      <div style={{ width: 300, height: 100, backgroundColor: 'lightgray', borderRadius: 30 }}>
      abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz<br />
      abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz<br />
      abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz<br />
      abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz<br />
      abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz<br />
      abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz<br />
      abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz<br />
      </div>
    </div>
```

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use position absolute and z-index :

```css
* {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    box-sizing: 0;
    font-size: 16px;
}
body {
    background: rgb(37, 37, 37);
    color: white;
}
#out-div {
    position: relative;
    margin: 40px;
    height: 200px;
    overflow-y: scroll;
    width: 650px;
    display: inline-block;
    z-index: 2;
    border-radius: 30px;
}
#in-div {
    font-size: 3rem;
    border-radius: 30px;
    overflow: hidden;
}
#fancy-background {
    border: 1px solid;
    background: rgb(93, 93, 93);
    border-radius: 30px;
    width: 610px;
    height: 200px;
    margin: 40px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    z-index: 1;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8" />
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
        <title>Document</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="./style.css" />
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="out-div">
            <div id="in-div">
                abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz<br />
                abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz<br />
                abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz<br />
                abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz<br />
                abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz<br />
                abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz<br />
                abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz<br />
                abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz<br />
                abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz<br />
                abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz<br />
                abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz<br />
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="fancy-background"></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use an SVG of a [rectangle](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Element/rect) with rounded corners as your background image to your outer div? You'd need to [encode](https://yoksel.github.io/url-encoder/) it to use it inline or link to it as an external svg image.

```css
.inner {
  width: fit-content;
  margin:0.25rem 1rem;
}

.outer {
  background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml,%3Csvg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' viewport='0 0 300 120' %3E%3Crect x='0' width='300' height='120' rx='15' fill='lightgray'/%3E%3C/svg%3E");
  width: 320px;
  height: 120px;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}
```

```html
<div class='outer'>
  <div class='inner'>
    abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz<br />
    abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz<br />
    abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz<br />
    abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz<br />
    abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz<br />
    abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz<br />
    abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz<br />
    abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz<br />
    abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz<br />
    abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz<br />
  </div>
</div>
```